# How to get norm of a row in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to get the norm of a row. I've written following code but it's not true!

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.rows(); i++)
        A.row(i) = A.row(i).array() / (A.row(i).norm());
```

It is worth mentioning, type of `A` is `MatrixXcf`. In your opinion, what's the problem?

Comment: What exactly doesn't match between your expectations and the actual output?

Comment: @iksemyonov, All of the elements of `A` become zero.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with your code. Anyways, what you wrote can be written more compact as either of these:

```
// assign result to new variable:
Eigen::MatrixXcf N = A.rowwise().normalized();
// or in-place normalization:
A.rowwise().normalize();
```